# Creating an application in N-Tier in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want an demo example for an N-Tier application in Silverlight so that using this example as a reference i can develop my application which is also to be  developed in same manner.
I have designed an application in Silverlight using N-tier but there are a lot of issues and i think m not using the right method to do it
Can anyone please provide me with such demo example or a link.It would be great if i can get a video tutorial.

Thankss

Comment: Can anyone guide me???? its urgent frnds

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please be informed that your above comment is considered bad form here.  Your question receives the same priority as anyone elses.

Answer (score 0):

Start here:  [The MVVM Pattern](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/the-mvvm-pattern) make sure you make it through to the WCF RIA Services chapter.